# Как узнать свободное место на гугл диске, android api

Tags: android, google-drive

Я использую Google drive api android и мне необходимо узнать

1. сколько свободного места осталось на гугл диске
2. сколько уже занято.

Как это сделать?
Или для этого необходимо прибегнуть к rest api?

Comment: Гляньте в метаданные файлов и папок Google Drive, там есть информация о размере каждого. То есть, зная нужную папку можно их получить. И если вы знакомы с эти м https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro то все просто. Ну а там сложить, и думаю будет все ок.

Comment: Да, общий размер можно узнать через 
DriveResourceClient.Query, указав пустой фильтр. Но как узнать оставшееся место. Я конечно могу вычитать из 15 ГБ, которые дают всем, но это не есть панацея.

Comment: Пришлось прибегнуть к ресту: About about = drive .about() .get() .setFields("storageQuota") .execute(); about.getStorageQuota().getLimit()